# If $P$ is on the circumcircle of a triangle, show that the feet of the perpendiculars from $P$ to the side-lines of the triangle are collienar

Tags: geometry, circles, plane-geometry

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $P$ be any point on its circumcircle. Let $X,Y,Z$ be the feet of the perpendiculars from $P$ onto lines $BC, CA$ and $AB$. Prove that points $X,Y,Z$ are collinear.

So I've already made a diagram(it is attached below), but I don't know how to prove it from there. Please help and explain your solution thoroughly because I have a test about this tomorrow and I want to understand this! Thank you! :D

[image]

Comment: There is no attachment.

Comment: sorry about that, i just added it

Comment: It is called [Simson Line](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://brilliant.org/wiki/simson-line-theorem/&ved=2ahUKEwje_a7dk_nqAhVGaCsKHbZPAzIQFjACegQIDhAL&usg=AOvVaw3j3N42rGKwXFMBb1KHdZM8).

Comment: I'm wondering how to prove this though

Comment: could you help me with that?

Comment: I don't think this were true for all P on triangle circumcircle.

Comment: Yeah but that's my assignment and I need to finish it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: 1]

The method of proof is to show that $\displaystyle \angle NMP+\angle PML=180^{\circ }$.

$\displaystyle PCAB$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, so $\displaystyle \angle PBA+\angle ACP=\angle PBN+\angle ACP=180^{\circ }$.

$\displaystyle PMNB$ is a cyclic quadrilateral (Thales' theorem), so $\displaystyle \angle PBN+\angle NMP=180^{\circ }$.

Hence $\displaystyle \angle NMP=\angle ACP$. Now $\displaystyle PLCM$ is cyclic, so $\displaystyle \angle PML=\angle PCL=180^{\circ }-\angle ACP$.

Therefore $\displaystyle \angle NMP+\angle PML=\angle ACP+(180^{\circ }-\angle ACP)=180^{\circ }$.

Comment: thank you so much for the clear diagram and the great solution! i really appreciate it!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Because $$\measuredangle AYX=\measuredangle APX=\measuredangle XPZ-\measuredangle APZ=180^{\circ}-\beta-\measuredangle APZ=$$
$$=\measuredangle APC-\measuredangle APZ=\measuredangle ZPC=\measuredangle ZYC.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Do you see some cyclic quads? there are 3 cyclic quads . Try to draw a neat diagram and you will observe the 3 cyclic quads.

Comment: thank  you, I'll look for the cyclic quads

Comment: Great! Actually the above solution ( which gave a diagram ) used the 3 cyclic quads. 
I would recommend you to at least  draw the diagram in geogebra and try to observe the cyclic quads on your own! It will help you a lot!